# NXT motors not moving?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, motor, repair

I've been looking around the net for a solution to this problem, to no avail.

After taking my NXT v1 out of storage, I tried using a motor, but it sortof just, moves back and forth once, then 'brakes' and resists any movement.
I did forget to take the batteries out when I stored it, and it was stored for about 4 months. 
I don't think its the motor, as all three, in all three ports and in different combinations do the same thing. Everything else is as normal on the NXT, even the rotation sensor measurements. Its only applying power to the motors that causes problems.

Just as a side note, if I try to add motors, it interferes with my program. One example is when I make a program with a Forward 5 block on the NXT, it stays on that block forever, with or without the motor connected. 
Another example is in a NXT-G program, it does the same thing, sticks on the motor command.

I will call tech support as a last option, I'm just wondering if anyone has any idea what could be wrong, and any way to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To work properly, the Forward 5 block on the NXT as well as the Move block of NXT-G require that TWO motors be connected on ports B and C. That's probably the problem you see... To test a single motor, there is the motor block.

Comment: Ugh, I literally just figured it out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Also would have upvoted but not enough reputation...